# unable to import pandas module

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I successfully installed pandas with

```
pip install --user pandas
```

Note that the option --user was necessary since without I ran into the following ownership  error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13]
Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I launched the jupyter notebook and failed to import pandas. Other libraries work fine, like numpy.

I suspect this is because python and pip are not in the same repository

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

which pip
/home/myname/.local/bin/pip
```

So I tried to set the $PYTHONPATH as follows

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/myname/.local/bin
```

but nothing changed. Is this maybe a jupyter issue or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what should I run with sudo?

Comment: You don't necessarily use `sudo` as others comment said. The right place you need to check is `import sys; sys.path` and `pip show pandas`. I think the installed places of pandas doesn't contained at `sys.path`, it is the right problems is. Please add these places to confirm this.

Comment: the location of pandas is `Location: /home/myname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and sys.path returns `/home/myname/sage-8.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` among others

Comment: You should install pandas through `anaconda prompt`. Search for `anacoda prompt` in your pc then use this command `conda install pandas`. Jupyter Notebook using different kernel from python installation. So pip from your CLI won't work on Jupyter. You have to install packages for Anaconda interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I was using Sage via the Jupyter notebook.
So the command

```
sage -pip install pandas
```

worked fine.